# PyCharam AddReferenceToFileAndPath Attribute Error

Tags: python, pycharm, dllimport

I am trying to access C# DLL using PyCharm. I am able to access the same DLL using IronPython.

Now, I want to access that DLL in pycharm and develop script.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"C:Calculation.dll")
```

I am getting  AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReferenceToFileAndPath' Error

Comment: How did you install clr?

Comment: pip install clr

Comment: Are you trying to use IronPython or CPython in PyCharm?

Comment: File with your script probably has name `clr.py` If true, rename it to something else.

Comment: @HFBrowning I have no idea, I am pretty new to this

Comment: What is the path to the interpreter (python.exe) that you're using? If you don't know, go to PyCharm > File > Settings > Project:<your_project> > Project Interpreter

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the guide you are following has a custom built, local module called clr.

The PyPi clr package is used to edit console string appearances.

In order to fix this, you will need to obtain the custom-built "clr" module provided by the author.

Comment: Did not understand what you saying. Can  you elobarate what is custom-built clr and who is the author ?

Comment: I am guessing you are following a guide someone wrote.

The clr package they refer to, is not the same one as "pip install clr".

They have a clr.py file in their project, that they are importing.